# Update color of plotline label on change highcharts

Tags: highcharts

is there a way to change color of the plotline label when the movement goes up and change it again in different font color when movement goes down?

```
      yAxis.addPlotLine({
        value: 66,
        color: 'red',
        width: 2,
        id: 'plot-line-1',
  label: {
                text: 66,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                 color: 'red',
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                y: newY,
                x: 0
            }
      });
```

Here is a working file http://jsfiddle.net/kttfv1h3/9/
thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You can add css style options to your plotLabel like to a simple object; [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Element.css)

```
var prev_val = 0; // global

        plotlabel = yAxis.plotLinesAndBands[0].label;
        if(prev_val <= y) {
            plotlabel.css({'color':'blue'});    
        } else {
            plotlabel.css({'color':'green'});   
        }
        prev_val = y;
```

My jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kttfv1h3/12/

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit with the different settings I found a way to achieve what you are seeking.

By delcaring a new variable `oldY`
And doing the following in `setInterval`, the label color changes depending on if the value is increasing or decreasing:

```
if(y < oldY) {
    yAxis.plotLinesAndBands["0"].label.element.style.fill = 'red';
} else {
    yAxis.plotLinesAndBands["0"].label.element.style.fill = 'green';
}
oldY = y;
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kttfv1h3/11/) for a working example based on the one you supplied.